# Print a Jinja2 list on a single line in a table element

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

If I have a list [1,2,3,4,5,6]

It prints out like 
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6

How can I get it to print without a line break between each like
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6?

Code except outputs in the TD like

```
            <tr>
                {% for field in LI %}
                    {% if field is not string and field is iterable %}
                        <td>
                            {% for item in field %}
                                {{item}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </td>
                    {% else %}
                        <td>{{ field }}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm, was an issue with CSS template forcing line breaks.  Works as expected.